Correct method of using metpy.calc.equivalent_potential_temperature: array or integer
I am attempting to calculate the equivalent potential temperature at an isobar (i.e. 1000mb, 925mb,  85mb, etc.) using the metpy function and the HRRR data stored on AWS, but I am running into an issue with the pressure variable I need to feed into the function. Normally, for none-isobar variable levels, there is a pressure variable that you can load in; however, with an isobar, they don't have that since all of the data points are going to be at the same pressure level. This is where I run into my problem, I have the temperature and dewpoint xarrays from the AWS repository, but no pressure values. When I attempt to feed in a pressure value, I am trying two different methods, and both give me different results.
The first method I am doing is applying xr.full_like to either the temperature or dewpoint xarray to create another xarray of the same shape, where all of its values are the pressure level of the isobar I am looking at, adding that array to the dataset with the other variables, and then passing all those arrays from the dataset that to the function. The other method is by just passing an integer of the isobar pressure level and adding units to it with and then passing the temperature and dewpoint arrays from the dataset to the function. I have called these ARRAY and SINGLE method respectively. Here is my code and the results I get back from it
Note: The xarray dataset I am using here is a 3d dataset with dimensions of (time, x, y) and it has temperature ['TMP'] and dewpoint ['DPT'] variables.
CODE:
def pressure_generator(ds: xr.Dataset, pressure_level: int) -> xr.Dataset:
    pressure_ds = xr.full_like(ds['TMP'], pressure_level).rename('PRES')
    pressure_ds.attrs['units'] = 'hPa' # adding units to make it work in the metpy function
    pressure_ds.attrs['long_name'] = 'pressure'
    ds['PRES'] = pressure_ds # adding the newly created array to the dataset as the PRES variable
    ds = ds.metpy.parse_cf()
    
    return ds
    
# Example of running the code at the 1000mb isobar
    ds = pressure_generator(ds, 1000) # the ds passed into the function here is a xr.Dataset containing 3D TMP and DPT array variables
    array_1000mb = mpcalc.equivalent_potential_temperature(ds['PRES'], ds['TMP'], ds['DPT'])
    single_1000mb = mpcalc.equivalent_potential_temperature(1000*units.hPa, ds['TMP'], ds['DPT'])

RESULTS (I have printed out the mean theta-e value for each method at each isobar level):
500mb
ARRAY METHOD
328.0
SINGLE METHOD
328.1153869628906

700mb
ARRAY METHOD
312.0
SINGLE METHOD
327.0259094238281

850mb
ARRAY METHOD
306.5
SINGLE METHOD
329.3340148925781

925mb
ARRAY METHOD
303.25
SINGLE METHOD
331.8924560546875

1000mb
ARRAY METHOD
300.0
SINGLE METHOD
334.6382141113281

As one can see, the mean values of theta-e are different for each method at each isobar and the single method appears to be more valid than the array method since its values actually increase as one gets closer to the surface of the earth, which is what one would expect. The metpy function is obviously broadcasting the single pressure value when running the function, but I cannot comprehend why passing an array with the same shape already as the other variables would produce a different value.

I tried, but failed, to reproduce this with a dataset I have. Can you reduce the example above to a small set of values that can be run without access to your original data? Or can you post the data and a complete, minimal example?
